# Passing case class between Scala and Flex using BlazeDS

Tags: apache-flex, scala, blazeds

When trying to pass a "case class" from Scala to Flex the results on Flex side are regular Object instead of UINamespace. Changing the case class to regular Java class and it arrives correctly.

The case class looks like this:

```
package com.scala.vo
case class UINamespace (@BeanProperty var name : String,
                        @BeanProperty var version : String,
                        @BeanProperty var parameters : java.util.List[String]) {
   def this() = this("", "", null)
}
```

Flex Side:

```
[RemoteClass(alias="com.scala.vo.UINamespace")]
public class UINamespace
{
    public var name : String;
    public var version : String;
    public var parameters : ArrayCollection;
}
```

Anyone managed to solve this?

**[Edited]** Changed null to regular object result.

Comment: Did you try a regular Scala class?  What were those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out again today and it worked. I am not sure what was the exact cause for it not to work when asking the question.

I'll leave the question here so if others have issues with case class, at least they will know that it should be working.